# Retrieving an uploaded image from a folder along with data in a row of a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Managed to upload images successfully, am now trying to view the image but am failing to. Am not getting an error. the rest of the data is outputted except the image.

**My model**

```
 function mycon(){

     $client_id = $this->session->userdata('client_id'); 
     $area = $this->session->userdata('area'); 
     $this->db->select('*'); // the select statement
     $this->db->where('client_id',$client_id);
     $this->db->or_where('consignment.status',0); 
     $this->db->or_where('consignment.status',1); 
     $this->db->or_where('consignment.status',2); 
     $q = $this->db->get('consignment'); // the table
     return $q;
 }
```

**Part of my controller**

```
  $data['v']=$this->Clientaccount_model->mycon();
```

**My View**

```
     <?php
     foreach ($v->result() as $row) {    ?>
     <section class="invoice">
     <div class="row invoice-info">
     <div class="col-sm-3 invoice-col">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/" width="100">              
     </div><!-- /.col -->
     <div class="col-sm-5 invoice-col">
     <address>
     LuggageID: <?php echo $row->luggage_id;?><br>
     Lagguage Location: <?php echo $row->l_area;?><br>
     Lagguage Destination: <?php echo $row->d_area;?><br>
     Lagguage Description: <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
     Date: <?php echo $row->dom;?><br>
     </address>
     <?php }  ?>
```

**My Table structure**

Columns 
luggage_id,
client_id,
l_area,
l_address,
d_area,
preferred,
dom,
tom,
description,
mass,
record_id,
filename,
size,
upload time,
status,

Image folder is uploads and its on the root

Comment: which it is the error that shows you the system

Comment: Hey. am not getting an error. but the image is not appearing. the rest is outputted except the image

Comment: I suppose that your filename row in your db is about your image, but in your view, you only have `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/" width="100">  `, never give the name of image like `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/<?= $row->filename?>" width="100"> `, isn`t it?

Comment: Thank you <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/<?= $row->filename?>" width="100"> worked .. post it as answer and i will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your filename row in your db is about your image, but in your view, you only have `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/" width="100">` , never give the name of image like `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/uploads/<?= $row->filename?>" width="100">` , isn`t it?